# Where do I find old versions of Android NDK?

Tags: android-ndk, android-ndk-r5, android-ndk-r4

Does anyone know where I can find older versions of the Android NDK? Our code doesn't build with r6. Surely there must be archived versions somewhere.

Comment: You can see all the old versions here: https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake/blob/master/ndk_links.md

Comment: These links ends with version 10, but the current one is 13 now.

Comment: @BhargavRao As a developer, this thread helped me several time to retrieve software I actually needed, I see it as a very relevant and pertinent question. There was no opinionated answer whatsoever.

Comment: Yep, @Antonio, It's a nice post, no doubt, but it is not on-topic for our site. It clearly asks for a "resource". (It is not on-topic -> close ; It is not a good post -> delete). If you can edit and make it not to do so, then I can reopen it, But IMO, it is better to leave it in this state. You can upvote the post and any of it's answers if you found them useful to you. But the post, as such, is not on topic. Regards.

Comment: all the old sdks could be found in: https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/wiki

Comment: Also, Google lets you download old NDKs here: developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html

Comment: All older release here : https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases

Comment: You can get here https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history

Answer (score 193):

Here are the links for Windows, Mac and Linux. Latest revision of 18.x, 17.x, 16.x, 15.x, 14.x, 13.x, 12.x, 11.x, 10.x, 9.x, 8.x and 7.x versions.

> **Update:** Download [Latest](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads) and [Old](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html) NDK releases from Android official site.

**Android NDK, Revision 18b (January 2019)**

> [Windows 32-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r18b-windows-x86.zip) | [Windows 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r18b-windows-x86_64.zip) | [Mac OS X 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r18b-darwin-x86_64.zip) | [Linux 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r18b-linux-x86_64.zip)

**Android NDK, Revision 17c (June 2018)**

> [Windows 32-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r17c-windows-x86.zip) | [Windows 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r17c-windows-x86_64.zip) | [Mac OS X 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r17c-darwin-x86_64.zip) | [Linux 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r17c-linux-x86_64.zip)

**Android NDK, Revision 16b (December 2017)**

> [Windows 32-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r16b-windows-x86.zip) | [Windows 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r16b-windows-x86_64.zip) | [Mac OS X 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r16b-darwin-x86_64.zip) | [Linux 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64.zip)

**Android NDK, Revision 15c (July 2017)**

> [Windows 32-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r15c-windows-x86.zip) | [Windows 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r15c-windows-x86_64.zip) | [Mac OS X 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r15c-darwin-x86_64.zip) | [Linux 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r15c-linux-x86_64.zip)

**Android NDK, Revision 14b (March 2017)**

> [Windows 32-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r14b-windows-x86.zip) | [Windows 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r14b-windows-x86_64.zip) | [Mac OS X 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r14b-darwin-x86_64.zip) | [Linux 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r14b-linux-x86_64.zip)

**Android NDK, Revision 13b (October 2016)**

> [Windows 32-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r13b-windows-x86.zip) | [Windows 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r13b-windows-x86_64.zip) | [Mac OS X 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r13b-darwin-x86_64.zip) | [Linux 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r13b-linux-x86_64.zip)

**Android NDK, Revision 12b (June 2016)**

> [Windows 32-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r12b-windows-x86.zip) | [Windows 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r12b-windows-x86_64.zip) | [Mac OS X 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r12b-darwin-x86_64.zip) | [Linux 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r12b-linux-x86_64.zip)

**Android NDK, Revision 11c (March 2016)**

> [Windows 32-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r11c-windows-x86.zip) | [Windows 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r11c-windows-x86_64.zip) | [Mac OS X 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r11c-darwin-x86_64.zip) | [Linux 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r11c-linux-x86_64.zip)

**Android NDK, Revision 10e (May 2015)**

> [Windows 32-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10e-windows-x86.exe) | [Windows 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10e-windows-x86_64.exe) | [Mac OS X 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r10e-darwin-x86_64.zip) | [Linux 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64.zip)

**Android NDK r9d**

> [Windows 32-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86.zip) | [Windows 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86_64.zip) | [Mac OS X 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9d-darwin-x86_64.tar.bz2) | [Linux 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9d-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2)

**Android NDK r8e**

> [Windows 32-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8e-windows-x86.zip) | [Windows 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8e-windows-x86_64.zip) | [Mac OS X 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8e-darwin-x86_64.tar.bz2) | [Linux 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8e-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2)

**Android NDK r7c**

> [Windows 32-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r7c-windows.zip) | [Mac OS X 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r7c-darwin-x86.tar.bz2) | [Linux 64-bit](https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r7c-linux-x86.tar.bz2)

Comment: @karmington I just checked, it works too!

Comment: For Android NDK r10c:
[Windows 64-bit](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10c-windows-x86_64.exe) | [Windows 32-bit](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10c-windows-x86.exe) | [Mac OS X 64-bit](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10c-darwin-x86_64.bin) | [Linux 32-bit (x86)](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10c-linux-x86.bin) | [Linux 64-bit (x86)](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10c-linux-x86_64.bin)

Comment: @Abhijeet Latest revision of NDK 10 is ````r10e```` so ````r10c```` is not included in the links.

Comment: why there is no NDK for linux 32 bit ? Isn't it supported ?

Comment: I keep trying to download r9d and i keep getting "Failed - Network error"

Comment: How to use Windows NDK r10e 64 bit as this is an .exe file and I'm unable to understand how to use it. I tried installing it but nothing happens

Comment: @MadanSapkota There exist some libraries that seem to support specific revisions of the NDK. For example, it may support r10d but not r10e.

Comment: @UtkarshSinha this is collection of latest revisions. it have nothing to do with support and libraries.

Comment: @ransh it's supported at least for `r9d`. Just follow [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9119814/673852).

Comment: Also, Google lets you download old NDKs here: developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html

Answer (score 192):

Looks like you can construct the link to the NDK that you want and download it from dl.google.com:

Linux example:
`http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9b-linux-x86.tar.bz2`
`http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9b-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2`

OS X example:
`http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9b-darwin-x86.tar.bz2`
`http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9b-darwin-x86_64.tar.bz2`

Windows example:
`http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9b-windows.zip`

**Extensions up to r10b:**
`.tar.bz2` for linux / os x and `.zip` for windows.

**Since r10c the extensions have changed to:**
`.bin` for linux / os x and `.exe` for windows

**Since r11:**

`.zip` for linux and OS X as well, a new URL base, and no 32 bit versions for OS X and linux.

`https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r11-linux-x86_64.zip`

Comment: I don't know why this is not the accepted answer this work well for me.

Comment: It does not always work.. e.g.: https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8b-darwin-x86_64.tar.bz2 -> 404 but https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8b-darwin-x86.tar.bz2 -> works fine. A pity Google does not have a proper page with older releases.

Comment: @stoiczek: The older NDKs didn't have all the builds the newer do. r8b probably didn't have 64-bit darwin build.

Comment: I was getting 404's until I realized that while Windows builds will be in a .zip archive, Mac and probably Linux will be a .tar.bz2 archive.

Comment: What does the 'darwin' mean? To get r10d adding in the 'darwin' makes it not work, and I've never seen it before.

Comment: darwin is MacOS X kernel

Comment: For windows downloads here is a sample url. Change the version as you like : https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8d-windows.zip

Answer (score 38):

A way to find out old download links is to use internet archive tools like "Way back machine", https://archive.org/web/. You can browse older web pages versions and get the links you want.

For example, I needed to download the NDK rev 9, so I used this tool to access the NDK download page (https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/) from March and the download link in March pointed to NDK rev 9.

Comment: This should be the best answer, just go to [http://web.archive.org/web/*/https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html](http://web.archive.org/web/*/https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) and pick a date soon after the version was released.

Answer (score 16):

I came across this just now doing the same search, and found the other answers are far too specific. I also google searched for downloading `android-ndk-r8` and found next to nothing. To get the correct version, I instead went here:

```
https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html
```

And copied the link to the download I needed, and pasted it into the URL bar. There, I edited the version to reflect what I wanted (for example, I changed `r8b` to `r8`). Then I pressed enter, and the correct download began.

As long as the naming conventions remain the same, this should work across all versions.

---

Edit: This convention did change. Some older versions are now available in the [archives](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html). For even older versions, refer to the links provided by [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28088215/763080).

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, as the naming conventions did change.

Comment: just press NDK Archives right there

Comment: Go to here https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html

Answer (score 14):

Looks like simply putting the link like this

http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r7c-windows.zip

on the address bar of your browser

The revision names (r7c, r8c etc.) could be found from the ndk download page

Comment: FYI for anyone needing the later r9 release: https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9d-windows.zip

Answer (score 5):

The 64 bit versions are available also:

http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8e-darwin-x86_64.tar.bz2

just replace the R8E release/version/iteration

Answer (score 3):

As user3486832 mentioned, you can use archive.org:
http://web.archive.org/web/*/https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: despite everyone's apparent success with manually manipulating URLs, the formats ARE changing over time, ex:  android-ndk-r10d-darwin-x86.bin vs android-ndk32-r10b-darwin-x86.tar.bz2 and **manual manipulation didn't work for me**.  This archive link is what I would consider an acceptable answer (since google doesn't appear to be removing the old files after they take down the links).

Answer (score 3):

Simply replacing **.bin** with **.tar.bz2** is not enough, for NDK releases older than **10b**. For example, https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10b-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 is not a valid link.

Turned out that the correct link for **10b** was: https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk32-r10b-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 (note the additional **'32'**). However, this doesn't seem to apply to e.g. **10a**, as this link doesn't work: https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk32-r10a-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 .

Bottom line: use http://web.archive.org until Google fixes this, if ever...

Comment: Good advise to use web.archive.org.. For what it's worth here's a link to the builds after r10b on the web.archive.org page (build r10e, but I could modify the link to get r10d): http://web.archive.org/web/20150602004400/http://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Google has moved NDK releases to GitHub. Now, [the Wiki page](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/wiki) contains links to the current stable release, to available betas, and to selected older releases.

Answer (score 1):

http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9d-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2

I successfully opened gstreamer SDK tutorials in Eclipse.

All I needed is to use an older version of ndk. specificly 9d.

(10c and 10d does not work, 10b - works just for tutorial-1 )

9d does work for all tutorials !
and you can:

1. Download it from:
   http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9d-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
2. Extract it.
3. set it in eclipse->window->preferences->Android->NDK->NDK location.
4. build - (ctrl+b).

Answer (score 0):

If you search Google for the version you want, you should be able to find a download link. For example, Android NDK r5b is available at http://androgeek.info/?p=296

On another note, it might be a good idea to look at why your code doesn't compile against the latest version and fix it.