# Where to find old versions of android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk

okay so many of you will tell that this is the duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849981/where-do-i-find-old-versions-of-ndk)

but ITS NOT !

that question was asked i think two years before and now you cant construct the path to previous ndk versions..i have been trying to construct the path for android ndk r8b for windows 7 64-bit but [here](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8b-windows-x86_64.zip) is the result.

anyone knows how to find previous ndk version

Comment: Clarify what you mean by *construct the path* ... ? And why putting in a linky to the zip from google and defining it "*here is the result*"?

Comment: What he means is: if you copy the URL for the latest version (r8e) and substitute a 'b' for the 'e' in an attempt to get version r8b, then you get a 404 error. I don't see why this question got downvoted either, it's perfectly on topic.

Comment: @NickT thank you for understanding...
it would be good if anyone helps me in finding r8b version..

Comment: Note that the linked topic is being constantly updated. I don't think we benefit from keeping [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766957/where-to-find-old-versions-of-android-ndk) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393873/old-versions-of-android-ndk.

Comment: This is NOT off-topic, it's a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849981/where-do-i-find-old-versions-of-android-ndk

Comment: This answer to the sited question addresses the author's problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25040676/431296

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NDK r8e is the first NDK with 32bit and 64bit releases. The prior ones were all 32bit and didn't have any suffix, so r8b would be:

https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8b-windows.zip

Comment: so will it work in win 7 64 bit with eclipse too 64 bit !! ??

Comment: Yes. Windows 7-64 can run 32-bit binaries just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The link in the other answer is for the r8b NDK which is pretty old. Unless you need that one specifically here's the link the most up-to-date r8 Win 64 version: https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8e-windows-x86_64.zip

Annoying that Google does not leave links to the old versions on their site

Comment: The files are never removed from http://dl.google.com/android/ndk; to see the relevant contents, look through [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/%2a/http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/)!