# Old Versions of Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

Any mirror sites that hold old versions of Android NDK?

I went to

[Android NDK Official Site](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

but it only contains the link to the latest version.

Old versions are described there, but no link is provided

Comment: This question is **not off-topic**. It's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766957/where-to-find-old-versions-of-android-ndk and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849981/where-do-i-find-old-versions-of-ndk

Answer (score 24, accepted):

copy the download link to the latest version of the ndk of your platform and change the version number according to the Revision information provided at the end of the page.

For example, the link to the latest version of NDK for Windows x64:

> http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9-windows-x86_64.zip

to download ndk r8e, just change the filename from android-ndk-r`9`-windows-x86_64.zip to android-ndk-r`8e`-windows-x86_64.zip

As site note, this site holds the copy to the last previous stable release of the NDK:

> http://mirror.sito.ir/Android/Android%20NDK/

thus, to get version other than r8e, you have to use the URL constructing method

EDIT:
Updated official older-releases NDK site:

> https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html

Comment: NDK r8e is the first NDK with 32bit and 64bit releases. The prior ones were all 32bit and didn't have any suffix, so r8b would be:

https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8b-windows.zip

Comment: and 9b would be https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9b-windows-x86_64.zip

Comment: The `mirror.sito.ir` site seems to be only accessible from Iran.

Comment: I found manual URL manipulation to be too difficult ( trying to get from android-ndk-r10d-darwin-x86.bin to android-ndk32-r10b-darwin-x86.tar.bz2 ), and this answer worked instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25040676/431296

Comment: updated official URL for NDK Archives: https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html