# How to download: Android NDK, Revision 8e

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to download Android NDK, Revision 8e (or any older revision) .. but I can't find any link in their [website](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) ..

I tried to follow the naming-convention as follow:

```
http:// ~ / android-ndk-r8e-linux.zip
```

but it doesn't work .. please help ..I am working on Linux

Comment: Is there any good reason why r9 won't work for you? For older versions of GCC, try the one with legacy toolchains.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: I am building an app that specifically asking for r8 .. but r8 didn't work because there are a file that doesn't exist which is needed by the makefile .. so I am moving to r8e hoping to find this file ..

Comment: That's rather rare; build tools are usually upwards compatible. What file? Maybe you should've asked a question about building said app with r9...

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: I didn't download r9 (not yet) as the app [building-guidance](http://www.olsr.org/?q=olsr_on_android) is specifically asking for r8. The error I get is: `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: not found`. when I checked the path, I discovered that I don't have the right _arm-linux-android_ version. So, instead of jumbing to r9 I would like to try r8e first ..

Comment: That's what r9 with legacy toolchains is for. It has obsolete versions of GCC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this links:

http://download.kiwix.org/dev/android-ndk-r8e-linux-i686.tar.bz2

http://download.kiwix.org/dev/android-ndk-r8e-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2

xcdwxcwxcwx cwxc wxc

Comment: i am able to download r8e now, thanks .. but it will be more useful if you pointed me toward where I can get these link from .. **well, teach me fishing instead of giving me a fish** .. thanks anyway

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849981/where-do-i-find-old-versions-of-android-ndk/29283394#29283394