# Android Eclipse and configuring NDK Toolchains for project

Tags: android, c++, windows, eclipse, android-ndk

I am using Android Eclipse ADT on Windows 8.1
I have installed both Cygwin and MinGW.
I have installed the SDK, NDK and Cocos2d-x library.

My question is that my Cocos2d-x project is expecting this toolchain library in the NDK:

```
ndk\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3\prebuilt\darwin-x86\lib\gcc\arm-linux-androideabi\4.4.3\include
```

I browse to the ndk\toolchains folder and I see several other versions:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-4.6
arm-linux-androideabi-4.8
arm-linux-androideabi-clang3.3
```

And a few other versions, but not the 4.4.3 version.

My question is then, should I

1) With Cygwin or MinGW compile "arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3" and how to do this.

- or -

2) With some setting in ADT should I change the version to the newest one "arm-linux-androideabi-4.8".  Please direct me to this setting if this is the correct choice.

Thanks in advance for your help!

---

**EDIT** More importantly than trying to put the right NDK in there, it clearly states, `"Invalid project path: Include path not found (C:\development\lib\android\ndk\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3\prebuilt\darwin-x86\lib\gcc\arm-linux-androideabi\4.4.3\include)"`
If that was a Visual Studio error I would look for where the Project Path is being defined.  Why can't I do that with Eclipse ADT?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you need a compiled arm-linux-arndroideabi-4.4.3 toolchain.

You can download the ndk-r8e toolchain with a compiled arm-linux-arndroideabi-4.4.3 from the following link:

32-OS: https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8e-windows-x86.zip

64-OS: https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8e-windows-x86_64.zip

Extra the zip file, you'll find android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3\prebuilt

Hope that helps.

Comment: Where did you find the other versions of the NDK? I visited [this page](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) which has a list of them, but I could not find the links to download.

Comment: The [NDK download page](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) just has newest version to download. I found the r8e version link by google search.

Comment: I found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139967/how-to-download-android-ndk-revision-8e) for the Linux version.