# Error compiling cocos2d-x v3.10 project

Tags: android, cmd, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to compile a new project on cmd using cocos2d-x v3.10, but the build is failing and I'm getting the following error:
[The output as seen on cmd.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDMME.png)

```
-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 29 source files to D:\Varun\MyApp\MyApp\cocos2d\cocos\platform
\android\java\bin\classes
    [javac] error: error reading D:\Varun\MyApp\MyApp\cocos2d\cocos\platform\android
\java\libs\._android-async-http-1.4.8.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed
in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed
in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use
-Xlint:-options.
    [javac] 1 error
    [javac] 3 warnings

BUILD FAILED
D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:601: The following
 error occurred while executing this line:
D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following
 error occurred while executing this line:
D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Compile faile
d; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 2 seconds
Error running command, return code: 1.
```

I'm using the following: 
JDK: 1.8.0_73 
Android api: 19 
NDK: r9 
Ant: 1.9.6 
Python: 2.7.11

Comment: NDK r10c+ is required to build Android games.

Comment: Is there libs._android-async-http-1.4.8.jar in the given directory?

Comment: @Zen I tried it again with ndk r10c and it gave the same error

Comment: @Alanmars that file is present at that location(D:\Varun\MyApp\MyApp\cocos2d\cocos\platform\android \java\libs._android-async-http-1.4.8.jar). Also the file has all access rights(permissions).

Comment: It's weird that I don't have `._android-async-http-1.4.8.jar` on my disk. Where did you download NDK? From Cocos?

Comment: Maybe the file D:\Varun\MyApp\MyApp\cocos2d\cocos\platform\android
\java\libs\._android-async-http-1.4.8.jar has been corrupted. It's weird that ._android-async-http-1.4.8.jar is a hidden file. Just rename ._android-async-http-1.4.8.jar to android-async-http-1.4.8.jar,  refer the  jar with the new name and have a try.

Comment: @Zen I got it from this link: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849981/where-do-i-find-old-versions-of-android-ndk

Comment: @Alanmars that didn't seem to make a difference

Comment: @Varun M, What did you do?

Answer (score 0):

I think `._android-async-http-1.4.8.jar` is a hidden file or the file is corrupted.

For case one, just rename it to `android-async-http-1.4.8.jar` and refer it to again.

For case two, just download a new one.