# difference between ndk-bundle and android-ndk-r15c

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

are there any difference between ndk-bundle obtained donloading the ndk from SDK manager and android-ndk-r15c from android developers?
I'm not able to compile a project cloned from git-hub, in the description is write that I need android-ndk-r8c... I'm using ndk-bundle, is the same??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `ndk-bundle` directory contains exactly same NDK as what you can download from https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html. But if the project is tuned for **r8c**, you may have some work to do to tune it for **r15c**.

This does not mean that you should [download r8c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849981/where-do-i-find-old-versions-of-android-ndk): some important bugs have been fixed, and there may be compatibility issues with new devices.