# how to build so files with different NDK version?

Tags: android, android-ndk

how to build so files with different NDK version? some times I need build so files with different NDK version, how to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

Got solution here:

firstly download the version of NDK you wanted from here:
[Where do I find old versions of Android NDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849981/where-do-i-find-old-versions-of-android-ndk/25040676#25040676)

then use the new downloaded ndk folder to replace your original ndk folder.
for example in my Mac, my original ndk folder is "/Users/Michael/Documents/sdk/ndk-bundle"
I downloaded the r9d version into my Downloads Folder, so I need change the folder name of r9d to my original folder:

`mv ~/Downloads/ndk-bundle-r9d /Users/Michael/Documents/sdk/ndk-bundle`

pls don't forget change the original folder to another name like following, so that you could change it back:

`mv /Users/Michael/Documents/sdk/ndk-bundle /Users/Michael/Documents/sdk/ndk-bundle-origin`